# Ring structure of $H^{\bullet}(\mathbb{R}P^{\infty},\,\mathbb{Z}/2)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, fibration

Let $\mathbb{R}P^{\infty}$ be the infinite real projective space. Its integral homology is given by
 $$
H_{i}(\mathbb{R}P^{\infty})=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
      \mathbb{Z} & \text{if }i=0 \\
      \mathbb{Z}/2 & \text{if }i\text{ is odd} \\
       0 &  \text{if }i>0\text{ and is even}\\
\end{array} \right.
$$

Then by the universal coefficient theorem, we can get that $H^{i}(\mathbb{R}P^{\infty},\,\mathbb{Z}/2)=\mathbb{Z}/2$ for all $i\geqslant0$. I want to know the ring structure of this $\mathbb{Z}/2$-coefficient cohomology.

Since $\mathbb{R}P^{\infty}$ is a model of $K(\mathbb{Z}/2,\,1)$, we can use the fibration
$$K(\mathbb{Z},\,1)\rightarrow K(\mathbb{Z}/2,\,1)\rightarrow K(\mathbb{Z},\,2)$$
and cohomology Leray-Serre spectral sequence to study $H^{\bullet}(\mathbb{R}P^{\infty},\,\mathbb{Z}/2)$. We apply $S^{1}$ to be a model of $K(\mathbb{Z},\,1)$ and $\mathbb{C}P^{\infty}$ to be a model of $K(\mathbb{Z},\,2)$. Then after some argument on $E_{2}$ page, we can get that as a $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$-algebra, $H^{\bullet}(\mathbb{R}P^{\infty},\,\mathbb{Z}/2)$ is generated by two elements $a$ and $b$ where $\deg(a)=1$ and $\deg(b)=2$. In fact, one has 
$$H^{2i+1}(\mathbb{R}P^{\infty},\,\mathbb{Z}/2)=\mathbb{Z}/2\cdot ab^{i}$$
and
$$H^{2i}(\mathbb{R}P^{\infty},\,\mathbb{Z}/2)=\mathbb{Z}/2\cdot b^{i}$$

However, I don't know that whether $a\cdot a=0$ or $b$.

If $a\cdot a=0$, then we have 
$$H^{\bullet}(\mathbb{R}P^{\infty},\,\mathbb{Z}/2)\cong \Lambda(a)\otimes \mathbb{Z}_{2}[b]$$

Otherwise, it is just generated by one element $a$ and 
$$H^{\bullet}(\mathbb{R}P^{\infty},\,\mathbb{Z}/2)\cong \mathbb{Z}_{2}[a]$$

Can anyone give me some help for this problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: The injection $\mathbb{R}P^{2}\to \mathbb{R}P^\infty$ implies a ring homomorphism on cohomology. Since $\mathbb{R}P^2$ is a manifold, we get that $a^2 = b$. Or you can make argument on cell cohomology.

Comment: I was thinking about the cup products on 1 or 2 cells, but I am not quite familiar with this geometric argument. Can you explain this in detail? Thanks.

Comment: For a start, look here at the relationship to intersection products, and take $\mathbb RP^2$ as your manifold.  If you can show that the 1-dimensional homology class has self-intersection number 1, you get that the cohomology class has nontrivial cup product. https://math.berkeley.edu/~hutching/teach/215b-2011/cup.pdf

Comment: If you have a $\Delta$ complex structure on $\mathbb R P^2$, then you can compute the cup product directly on chains. This is described on p. 53, example 37.2 of these notes: http://www.ms.uky.edu/~guillou/F15/654Notes.pdf